# CreateMaterialTopTabNavigator navigation is slow

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

**CreateMaterialTobTabNavigator is very laggy when navigating between the tabs .**

I have used three navigators in my code. drawer Navigator has stack and tab navigator, and the default loading is the 'tab navigator' made with createMaterialTopTabNavigator.

While navigator between the tabs of the tabnavigator , there is some glitches and jittering , which clearly is very annoying .

Tested  in both android and ios devices.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: True ! It's very laggy and yet haven't found the solution. I had to pause the project just because of it and finding proper alternative out there.

Comment: Still facing the problem. Anyone found the solution?